# Query a large MySQL table without any joins

Tags: mysql, performance, large-data

I am stuck up in a typical situation where I have a MySQL  5 table with 3 million records. The table itself is simple and straight forward.

```
| id |  Product |  Price |
|------------------------|
| 1  |  Prod A  |  25    |
| 2  |  Prod B  |  25    |
| 3  |  Prod C  |  12    |
| 4  |  Prod D  |  10    |
| 5  |  Prod E  |  25    |
| 6  |  Prod F  |  11    |
| 7  |  Prod G  |  25    |
| 8  |  Prod H  |  25    |
| 9  |  Prod I  |  19    |
| 10 |  Prod J  |  25    |
--------------------------
```

I run a simple query  like this

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM large_source 
 WHERE Price >=10 AND id >=".$starting_id." 
       AND id <=".$ending_id." 
 ORDER BY id ASC"
```

I am fetching the results in the same page inside IFRAMES. So when user clicks the Load button it will fetch the next set of results from STARTING ID to ENDING ID.

If I run the query from any STARTING ID to ENDING ID inside the shell or PhpMyAdmin, the query takes less than 1 sec to return the results. But, in my PHP page, the first 2 sets come quite fast, but as we are loading subsequent sets, the rendering is getting slower and slower.

I am unable to figure out the reason. I have tried every possible measure to optimize and normalise the table. It has no joins and ids are also sequential. So, what can be the reason for rendering it slow. All are different pages inside IFRAME so as not to freeze the browser. All MySQL connections are closed after each set call.

Note: I cannot avoid IFRAMES, because the backend support people will be working on different sets, where they can click on different icons beside each row.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate strings to make your query, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Also, if you have indexes in your id column, it may be not an SQL problem but a PHP problem (and you didn't upload your code)

Comment: How many records are your showing in the iframe?

Comment: I am showing around 100 records in each iframe.

Comment: 'id' itself is the Primary Key and you can see in the query - the WHERE clause is only using the id.

Comment: Show us the actual SQL query.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.